# Javacsript not working after loading new category

Tags: javascript, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I added some JavaScript code in to Prestahop's 1.7 custom.js file because I wanted to change the class of the category product's div on hover. The code works but if I load the next category or choose any filter from the layered navigation the code stops working and it works only if I reload the page. I guess it has to do with the Ajax call for loading the results and the next category but I'm not very good with JavaScript.
Any idea on how I could make the code to work after the loading of new category or filter results?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
$(".product-box").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("current");
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass("current");
});
```

Comment: any working example?

Comment: Why not style the elements using the selector `.product-box:hover`?

Comment: Is it possible that loading new results replaces the old product boxes with new ones that haven't gotten the event handlers assigned? You'll just have to add them again after each reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned by DustInCompetent, if its simply to add some css styling to it, you can achieve it by using `.product-box:hover`.

If your going to want to do JS stuff as well, odds are the **.product-box** are being loaded dynamically. So your .hover function wont work for new elements added to the DOM. You could use something like this :

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
    }
}, ".product-box"); //pass the element as an argument to .on
```